# How to run a SQL with multiple projects in it using python? (A google credential problem)

Tags: python, google-bigquery, credentials

I have a simple SQL text: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project1.dataset1.table1 t1 INNER JOIN project2.dataset2.table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id`
Just an example. The layout of the tables is not our concern.

I also have a credential json file: project1.json
Containing the information bellow:
{
"type":"service_account",
"project_id":"project1",
"private_key_id": ...,
"private_key": ...,
...
}

So this is my code:

```
        import os
        from google.cloud import bigquery
        from google.oauth2 import service_account
        credentials_json = 'project1.json'
        os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credentials_json
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            credentials_json,
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
        )
        client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)
        sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM project1.dataset1.table1 t1 INNER JOIN project2.dataset2.table2 t2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id'
        rows = client.query(sql).result()
```

The problem is an error occurred. 
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: Table project2:dataset2.table2: User does not have permission to query table project2:dataset2.table2.

What should I do to run that SQL

Comment: Fix the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Every service account has an email address. First, obtain that e-mail address.

Then go to project2's permissions and add service account's email for BigQuery permissions such as BigQuery Viewer, BigQuery Owner, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is exactly what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to the BigQuery UI in [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery).

2.Select `project2` from the project's drop down menu.

3.Select a `dataset2` from Resources, then click `Share dataset` near the right side of the window.

4.In the Share dataset panel, in the Dataset permissions tab, enter the service account you want to add into the `Add members` text box.

5.For `Select a role`, select BigQuery and choose an appropriate pre-defined IAM role for the service account. For example `Viewer` for read only access.

This procedure is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#controlling_access_to_a_dataset). Please note that, depending on the permissions you have in `project2`, you may need a project Owner or BigQuery Admin to perform these steps for you.

If necessary repeat these steps for `project1.dataset1`, although based on the error you are getting, you may already have permissions on that one.